# Chrome Extension - Javascript loaded but function is not defined when calling it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I thought everything was well with my extension, it was loading the js libraries successfully on most of the domains I've tested my extension on, then I found a few domains where it seemed the libraries wasn't being loaded.

I am using the Google Web Font Loader library, and including it in my contentscript.js, which injects it to the page like this:

```
// Add Google Webfont Library
    var gwebfont = document.createElement("script");
    gwebfont.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js";
    var callback = function (){ 
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        var code = "WebFont.load({google: { families: ['Open Sans', 'Open Sans:light', 'Open Sans:semi-bold', 'Open Sans:bold'] } });";
        try {
          s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
          shadow.appendChild(s);
        } catch (e) {
          s.text = code;
          shadow.appendChild(s);
        }
    }
    gwebfont.onload = callback;
    shadow.appendChild(gwebfont);
```

Yes, I do have the folder set in `web_accessible_resources` and the `contentscript.js` is also running..

On the few domains this doesn't work, it says `WebFont is not defined`, but on most of the domains I've tested this on, it works without any problem.

When I check in the Network tab in Chrome, I can see the webfont.js was loaded.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why only some domains give me the not defined error, when it appears the library was loaded?

I have also tried to run the code again in the console, and on the few domains where it doesn't work, it gives me the same not defined error.

This code doesn't work on hungry.dk, works on stylepit.dk

Here's a snippet of the event

[image]

Let me know if u want a closer look at something in here..

Comment: It could be that CORS is preventing it from loading on some sites. It might be worth adding an argument to the `callback` function, in case it gets called with some kind of useful error message.

Comment: I'll take a look at that tomorrow morning, thanks. But just weird, as the Network tab kinda shows it was loaded, but obviously it's not, since I can't call the function.

Comment: web_accessible_resources is applicable only to packaged resources, but you load the script from an external site which is why page CSP kicks in.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I did load the file locally, but decided to add the link for it instead, so it would be easier for u guys to try and replicate the problem. Also, this does also work on most domains.

Comment: @DavidKnipe ALright I got the event log now, anything specific I should look for?

Comment: @Anders I don't know where the documentation for `onload` is, so I don't know what arguments to expect, if any. What do you see in the log? Regarding your first comment, that sounds like a race condition (the script does load, but it's too late). What happens if you enter `WebFont` into the console manually, after everything else has loaded?

Comment: The race thing crossed my mind as well, I did try to enter the code in the console, but with the same result, as mentioned in the question. An event is returned, will post a screenshot above.